# In Javascript forEach, loop until result of function is not false

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-6, foreach

I'm building a battlship game in javascript.

What I want: within a forEach loop, to execute a function again and again until the result is not false.

I'm trying to write DRY code. This result works but requires needless repetition, there must be a simpler, more elegant way to get this result.

The setup is this:
The game has a board of many boardUnit objects. Each boardUnit has a coordinate, and a boolean to specify if there is a ship on it (hasShip:false or true).

Ships take up multiple units depending on their length (with lengths of 1,2,3,4 or 5)

The result I want is this:

1. Generate a set of sequential random coordinates based on ship length (Example [[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]) // Works OK
2. Check boardUnits with matching coordinates to see if hasShip is false or true // Works OK
3. If any of the boardUnits has hasShip:true, generate new coordinates and repeat the loop // Here is where I need help
4. If all boardUnits have hasShip:false, update boardUnits so selected coordinates have hasShip set to true. // Works OK

```
let ships = [{ length: 3 }, { length: 2 }, { length: 5 }];
let boardUnits = [
  { name: "unit1", coordinates: [1, 1], hasShip: false },
  { name: "unit2", coordinates: [1, 2], hasShip: false },
  // and on to 100
];

function placePlayerShipsOnBoard(player) {
  //The following function should be executed until result is not false

  function placeShipInUnit(coordinates, ship) {
    // Find input coordinates in boardUnits
    // Returns array of boardUnits (Ex. [{name:unit 31, coordinates: [3,1], hasShip: false},{name:unit 32, coordinates: [3,2], hasShip: false}, {name:unit 33, coordinates: [3,3], hasShip: false}])

    let selectedUnits = filterUnit(coordinates);

    // Checks if any of the board Units has hasShip:true. If unit has a ship, exits function

    if (!spaceChecker(selectedUnits)) {
      return false;
    }

    // Clones boardUnits, and updates units with specified coordinates with hasShip:true (Ex. {name:unit 33, coordinates: [3,3], hasShip: true})

    boardUnits = updateUnits(boardUnits, selectedUnits, true);
  }

  // ****** This is the function I need help with

  ships.forEach((ship) => {
    // Generate array of coordinates based on ship length (Ex. Ship of length three results in  [[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]). Works OK

    const coordinates = generateRandomCoordinates();

    // Check if function is false. If false, it means that the units in the specified coordinates have a ship. Need help.

    checkIfValid = placeShipInUnit(shipCoordinates, ship);

    // If all boardUnits have hasShip: false, then execute function that changes "hasShip" to true in specified boardUnits. Need help.

    if (checkIfValid != false) {
      placeShip(shipCoordinates, ship);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Things become easier if you maintain the grid data structure, with for each cell which state it has.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, the boardUnits variable could have the indexes paired with the coordinates. This will make it simpler to access a board unit and retrieve its status.

Also it would be a good idea to automate it. An example of a function with the attributes you showed initially:

```
function initBoard(xSize, ySize) {
    let boardUnits = [];
    let unitNumber = 1;
    for (let x = 0; x < xSize; x++) {
        boardUnits[x] = [];
        for (let y = 0; y < ySize; y++) {
            boardUnits[x].push({name: "Unit "+unitNumber, hasShip: false});
            unitNumber++;
        }
    }
    return boardUnits;
}

// Init Board
const boardUnits = initBoard(10, 10);
```

Now, for the part where you check if the coordinates have a ship or not. You have the coordinates generated randomly, so you can check each of those if there is a ship or not (if you use coordinates from 1, you need to subtract 1 from the board coordinates, which I left commented):

```
ships.forEach((ship) => {
    let isEmptyCoordinates = false;
    let coordinates = [];

    while (!isEmptyCoordinates) {
        // As the exception is to have a ship on it, we re-start the variable isEmptyCoordinates to true
        isEmptyCoordinates = true;
        coordinates = generateRandomCoordinates();
    
        coordinates.forEach((coordinate) => {
            // Use this one if coordinates generated starts from 0
            if(boardUnits[coordinate[0]][coordinate[1]].hasShip){
                isEmptyCoordinates = false;
            }
            // Use this one if coordinates generated starts from 1
            // if(boardUnits[coordinate[0] - 1][coordinate[1] - 1].hasShip){
            //     isEmptyCoordinates = false;
            // }
        });
    }

    placeShip(coordinates, ship);
});
```

Comment: This is a good alternative. Now, the question would remain: If the generated coordinates are not empty, how do I keep generating coordinates until empty coordinates are found?

Comment: @heyslevin the improvement you suggested is almost correct. However you want to leave the loop when the coordinates are empty. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) as well as [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) are the tools for any boolean based validation of array entries ...

```
let isEmptyCoordinates = coordinates.every(coordinate =>
  !boardUnits[coordinate[0]][coordinate[1]].hasShip
);
if (isEmptyCoordinates) {
  placeShip(coordinates, ship);
}
```

... or even ...

```
if (coordinates.every(coordinate =>
  !boardUnits[coordinate[0]][coordinate[1]].hasShip
)) {
  placeShip(coordinates, ship);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm looking for a way to create a loop that will continue to generate coordinates until all coordinates have hasShip: false.

Meaning, If any of the boardUnits has property hasShip: true, the loop would generate new coordinates.

Not sure why we're getting downvoted either.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe wrapping your code @Eduardo in a while loop can keep running the loop until empty coordinates are found:

```
let isEmptyCoordinates = true;

while (isEmptyCoordinates === true) {
  coordinates = generateRandomCoordinates();

  coordinates.forEach((coordinate) => {
    if (boardUnits[coordinate[0]][coordinate[1]].hasShip) {
      isEmptyCoordinates = false;
    }
  });
}

if (isEmptyCoordinates) {
  placeShip(coordinates, ship);
}
```